# Loop through and rename files

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I'm trying to loop through a folder that contains a bunch of other folders with titles Spec01, Spec02, Speco03,...,Spec14. Each of the Spec folders has a handful of files but the one I need is called specimen.dat in each folder. I want to loop through each folder, convert it to an Excel file, and save it with the name of the parent folder i.e. Spec##.

The pandas portion of my code work fine on it's own but when I added the for-loop I would end up with only one file named [].xlsx. I believe my loop is just writing over itself

Here's my code I'm working with

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

your_path = 'C:/Users/abh85/Desktop/AAA/'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(your_path):
    for subdir in files:
            if subdir.endswith('.dat'):
                with open(os.path.join(root, subdir)) as f1:
                    #change skiprow as needed
                    df = pd.read_csv(f1, sep='\s+', skiprows = 4, error_bad_lines = False) 
                    df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors ='coerce')
                    df = df.dropna() #drop blank rows from coerce process
                    #manually change column names per test data acquisition
                    df.columns = ['Time (s)', 'Displacement (mm)', 'ExDisp (mm)', 'CMOD (mm)', 'Force (kN)']
                    df.to_excel('C:/Users/abh85/Desktop/xls/%s.xlsx' %dirs, index=False)
```

I know the renaming isn't working because how I'm calling "dirs" in the loop. The following code gives me the names I want but I don't know how to incorporate it:

```py
import os 

your_path = 'C:/Users/abh85/Desktop/AAA/'
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(your_path):
    for name in dirs:
        print(name)
```

I can upload a zip with the sample folders.

Comment: Have you tried printing `'C:/Users/abh85/Desktop/xls/%s.xlsx' %dirs` for each loop? I think you are appending the wrong thing to your excel path ('C:/Users/abh85/Desktop/xls/%s.xlsx' %dirs). I believe you shouldn't be using `dirs` to append to the path but something else. I think you want to use `root` instead of `dir` like so: `'C:/Users/abh85/Desktop/xls/%s.xlsx' %(os.path.basename(root))`

Comment: Thanks for the tip...it was just printing [] each loop. It gave me an idea for my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

So, I came up with this. I'm still a novice to Python so I'm not sure if this is the most efficient answer but it seems to do the trick:

```
import os

your_path = 'C:/Users/abh85/Desktop/AAA/'
file_names = []

i = 0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(your_path):
    for name in dirs:
        file_names.append(name)


    for subdir in files:
            if subdir.endswith('.dat'):
                with open(os.path.join(root, subdir)) as f1:
            #change skiprow as needed
                          df = pd.read_csv(f1, sep='\s+', skiprows = 4, error_bad_lines = False) 
                          df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors ='coerce')
                          df = df.dropna() #drop blank rows from coerce process
            #manually change column names per test data acquisition
                          df.columns = ['Time (s)', 'Displacement (mm)', 'ExDisp (mm)', 'CMOD (mm)', 'Force (kN)']
                          df.to_excel('C:/Users/abh85/Desktop/xls/%s.xlsx' %file_names[i], index=False)
                          i += 1
```